# Calculate area in each of the SpatialLines in a SpatialLinesDataFrame

Tags: spatial, r-sp

Is it possible to calculate the area inside each SpatialLines in a SpatialLinesDataFrame?

I was lloking for a method to calculate the individual area as well as the mean of the total number of areas.

Comment: `SpatialLines` don't have area's as they are (collections of) lines. Do you mean areas of `SpatialPolygons` elements?

Comment: So i would have to convert each line in the SpatialLinesDataFrame into polygons first and then calculate the area?

Comment: So. How do I convert the SpatialLinesDataFrame lines into polygons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. Lets first creat some dummy data:

```
library(sp)
l1 <- Lines(list(Line(cbind(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1), c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0)))), "1")
l2 <- Lines(list(Line(cbind(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1), c(0, 5, 5, 0, 0)))), "2")
ls <- SpatialLines(list(l1, l2))
```

As expected, lines do not have an area:

```
library(rgeos) 
gArea(ls, byid = TRUE)
```

Lets convert the `SpatialLines` to `SpatialPolygons`

```
ps <- SpatialPolygons(
  lapply(1:length(ls), 
         function(i) Polygons(lapply(coordinates(ls)[[i]], function(y) Polygon(y)), as.character(i))))

gArea(ps, byid = TRUE)
```